# Java - how to get dependencies to ignore each other?

Tags: java

We are developing a fairly large project and have many dependencies.  Recently, we ran into an issue with a conflict between two of them, agileAPI.jar and axis.jar.  Both are 3rd party libraries.

The code in question depends directly on agileAPI.jar.  If I build it with just that in the build path, everything that depends on it works correctly.

As soon as I add axis.jar to the build path (just adding it, not writing code that depends on it), everything goes wrong.  Some of the code that depended on the first library is now throwing exceptions from the 2nd library.  It is as if the first library is picking and choosing methods to call from the 2nd library, instead of whereever it was calling them from prior.

I have code in the project that needs axis.jar directly, so I can't just remove it from the build path.  I need to find a way to have these two exist in the same build path, but ignore each other.

It should be noted that both libraries coexisted prior to a recent upgrade with agile.  I have been working with Oracle's support team to try and resolve this.  After two weeks, though, I am looking for other sources of help.

Our environment is Windows and Eclipse, although in testing this, it also occurs when running java from a command line.  Our JDK is 1.5.0_22.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

David

EDIT:

As requested, here are the stack traces that we see.  The first stack trace is printed in the code beyond my control:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.axis.description.OperationDesc.setStyle(Lorg/apache/axis/constants/Style;)V
  at com.agile.webfs.components.fileserver.client.FileServerSoapBindingStub._initOperationDesc1(FileServerSoapBindingStub.java:37)
  at com.agile.webfs.components.fileserver.client.FileServerSoapBindingStub.<clinit>(FileServerSoapBindingStub.java:20)
  at com.agile.webfs.components.fileserver.client.FileServerWSServiceLocator.getFileServer(FileServerWSServiceLocator.java:43)
  at com.agile.webfs.client.IFSLocator.getRemoteFileServer(IFSLocator.java:128)
  at com.agile.webfs.client.IFSLocator.getConnection(IFSLocator.java:101)
  at com.agile.api.pc.EJBLookup.createFileSession(EJBLookup.java:444)
  at com.agile.api.pc.EJBLookup.getFileSession(EJBLookup.java:432)
  at com.agile.api.pc.attachment.IFSOutputStream.getFileSession(IFSOutputStream.java:133)
  at com.agile.api.pc.attachment.IFSOutputStream.copyFrom(IFSOutputStream.java:87)
  at com.agile.api.pc.attachment.IFSOutputStream.copyFrom(IFSOutputStream.java:115)
  at com.agile.api.pc.TableAttachment.uploadFile(TableAttachment.java:886)
  at com.agile.api.pc.TableAttachment$AddFiles2Action.doSdkAction(TableAttachment.java:724)
  at com.agile.api.common.SDKAction.run(SDKAction.java:23)
  at com.agile.api.common.OracleAuthenticator.doAs(OracleAuthenticator.java:131)
  at com.agile.api.common.Security.doAs(Security.java:54)
  at com.agile.api.common.Security.doAs(Security.java:109)
  at com.agile.api.pc.TableAttachment.addFiles2(TableAttachment.java:483)
  at com.agile.api.pc.TableAttachment.createNewBlob2(TableAttachment.java:459)
  at com.agile.api.pc.TableAttachment.doCreateServerRowWithParam(TableAttachment.java:363)
  at com.agile.api.pc.Table.createTableRow(Table.java:238)
  at com.agile.api.pc.TableAttachment.createTableRow(TableAttachment.java:169)
  at com.agile.api.pc.Table.createRow(Table.java:202)
  at com.[snip].updateAttachments(VaultImportService.java:3068)
  at com.[snip].processIncorporatedFile(VaultImportService.java:926)
  at com.[snip].processPdxFile(VaultImportService.java:532)
  at com.[snip].processPdxRequest(VaultImportService.java:388)
  at com.[snip].<init>(VaultImportService.java:299)
  at com.[snip].main(VaultImportService.java:3660)
```

After the exception bubbles up and we catch it, the stacktrace that we print looks like:

```
 at com.agile.api.pc.Session.createError(Session.java:1772)
 at com.agile.api.pc.EJBLookup.createFileSession(EJBLookup.java:454)
 at com.agile.api.pc.EJBLookup.getFileSession(EJBLookup.java:432)
 at com.agile.api.pc.attachment.IFSOutputStream.getFileSession(IFSOutputStream.java:133)
 at com.agile.api.pc.attachment.IFSOutputStream.copyFrom(IFSOutputStream.java:87)
 at com.agile.api.pc.attachment.IFSOutputStream.copyFrom(IFSOutputStream.java:115)
 at com.agile.api.pc.TableAttachment.uploadFile(TableAttachment.java:886)
 at com.agile.api.pc.TableAttachment$AddFiles2Action.doSdkAction(TableAttachment.java:724)
 at com.agile.api.common.SDKAction.run(SDKAction.java:23)
 at com.agile.api.common.OracleAuthenticator.doAs(OracleAuthenticator.java:131)
 at com.agile.api.common.Security.doAs(Security.java:54)
 at com.agile.api.common.Security.doAs(Security.java:109)
 at com.agile.api.pc.TableAttachment.addFiles2(TableAttachment.java:483)
 at com.agile.api.pc.TableAttachment.createNewBlob2(TableAttachment.java:459)
 at com.agile.api.pc.TableAttachment.doCreateServerRowWithParam(TableAttachment.java:363)
 at com.agile.api.pc.Table.createTableRow(Table.java:238)
 at com.agile.api.pc.TableAttachment.createTableRow(TableAttachment.java:169)
 at com.agile.api.pc.Table.createRow(Table.java:202)
 at com.[snip].updateAttachments(VaultImportService.java:3068)
 at com.[snip].processIncorporatedFile(VaultImportService.java:926)
 at com.[snip].processPdxFile(VaultImportService.java:532)
 at com.[snip].processPdxRequest(VaultImportService.java:388)
 at com.[snip].<init>(VaultImportService.java:299)
 at com.[snip].main(VaultImportService.java:3660)
```

In both cases, the line "at com.agile.api.pc.Table.createRow(Table.java:202)" is the agileAPI call that I am making.  I have removed our package structure, as it identifies the company that I work for.  They value privacy and security.

Comment: Which version of axis is that jar file from?

Comment: Are there name conflicts between the libraries? I'm guessing Oracle would have already suggested this, but can you just be explicit in your code (i.e. when declaring variables, putting their full package name in front of them, like `com.package.Foo foo = new Foo();`?

Comment: Did you try to change the order in the classpath. If you have luck it will work. Anyway, can you give some more details about the error message and the origin of this libs.

Comment: @normalocity Being "explicit" will not change anything because the compiler will do this automatically, resolving imports as needed.

Comment: @PeterMmm With custom class loaders in some containers or projects, it's probably best not to rely on this. I'm not even certain the Sun JRE class loaders are required to take classpath order into account. Maybe they do, but I'd never bet on it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise you to check these two things first:

- Open the axis.jar file with some zip utility, like 7-Zip or WinRar. See if there's a folder called "services" in the META-INF folder in the jar. If there is, it's possible that the axis.jar file specifies implementations for specific interfaces that somehow don't interoperate with agileAPI. Also do the same for agileAPI.jar, since it might itself declare an interface implementation that axis doesn't like.
- Open both agileAPI.jar and axis.jar with a zip utility, then check if there's packages with the same name. If there's none, it won't be a naming conflict. If there's one or more, open the corresponding folders and do the same check recursively. If you end up with at least one class with the same name in the same package across the two jars, it's probably a naming conflict.

That should catch the most obvious issues. If none of this is the case, we'll need to look deeper.

Comment: Sorry, there were a lot of files to go through. Neither jar file has a services folder in the meta folder. And neither manafest specifies anything of importance, either.

Between the two files, they share 7 classes that have the same name.  However, they are in different folders.  My prefered environment is .Net, so I am a bit newbish with Java and packages, but I believe that means they are in different packages?

Also, the beginning folder structure of both files is different.  All of the classes in axis.jar start in org/apache/axis...  and AgileAPI.jar start in com/agile/...

Comment: @Eckish So I guess the next most likely issue is a naming conflict, like others suggested. See if you can find classes with the same name in the same package path.

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  I am new to Stack overflow.  I tried to start a new paragraph and ended up submitting early.

Comment: @Eckish Yeah, that happened a couple times to me as well at first :D Well, it looks like there's no naming conflicts. The folders in the jar are indeed the package structure. Guess that rules out the basic stuff. We're gonna need to see a stack trace of the exception you're getting to figure out more. You can just add that to your original post as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve such classpath issues is to use a module system such as OSGi or the NetBeans Platform module system where each module has its own classloader.